# react native upload file form data

Tags: asp.net, .net, react-native, file-upload, multipartform-data

it is work fine on post man so i copy the whole code from post mane

formdata.append("file_1", fileInput.files[0], "file.pdf");

and i change fileInput.files[0]to response from react native document picker

my problem i am getting an error on line 166 and this is below back end side code

this code built the .net

```
 line 166             attachments.Add(new OpportunityAttachmentInfo()
                {
                    ContentType = file.ContentType,
                    FileData = content,
                    FileName = fileDate.FileName + 
                    file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".")),
                    AttachmentTypeId = request[i].AttachmentTypeId,
                });
            }
```

this is my react native code

```
  uploadFIle = async (res) => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.props.accessToken);
 
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', res, res.name);
    formdata.append(
      'data',
      JSON.stringify({
       ****
      }),
    );

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: formdata,
      redirect: 'follow',
    };

    fetch(
      'https://****',
      requestOptions,
    )
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('result', result);

        this.apiGetSupplierItem();
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
  };
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a react-native question. Perhaps you should provide both your react-native code with the backend code and the technology on which the backend(API) is built

Comment: `react-native-document-picker` return reference path URI on device disk       `fileInput.files[0]` which not contains actually document data. You should either fetch document data as BLOB or BASE64 as per target backend supported format.